# jQuery tab issue - find out active tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I have a website that has 6 tabs using [jQuery-UI tab widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/). When the website opens up, I disable all tabs except the first one.

The problem I have is that when the user clicks the disable tabs, the event handler "`click`" continues to function reporting the tab numbers.  I would like to suppress that because is causing problems for me.

```
 if ($("Main").tabs( "option", "active" )) // <--------- I changed it to this
 { //open disabled tabs
   continue doing something....
 } //close disabled tabs
```

Of course, this did not work

Comment: It doesn't return a boolean value. It returns an array with the indexes. Check the documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-disabled

Comment: Hi MelanciaUK, from the documentation it states Boolean or Array (upper right hand corner).  Then on the getter, which I imagine what the Boolean would be it shows an example.  Of course that is what I am showing above and have tried and it doesn't work.  I don't think they did a good job at explaining how to use the getter and setter and how they work and what it returns.

Comment: I find that activated = x.fn.x.init[0], I don't know if this means tab 0? If it does mean tab 0, how can I create a condition (if statement), which checks if it is x.fn.x.init[0], don't execute what's in parenthesis?

Comment: So based on the comment of MeanciaUK is it correct that you are using [jqueryui-tabs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/)?

Comment: yes, that is correct.  I am trying to find out which tab is currently active, if it is tab 0 the first tab, then when the user clicks on the other tabs(that are currently disabled), I will ignore the click event.

Answer (score 0):

activeType: Boolean or Integer

Default: 0
Which panel is currently open.
Multiple types supported:
Boolean: Setting active to false will collapse all panels. This requires the collapsible option to be true.
Integer: The zero-based index of the panel that is active (open). A negative value selects panels going backward from the last panel.
Code examples:
Initialize the tabs with the active option specified:

1
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ active: 1 });
Get or set the active option, after initialization:

1
2
3
4
5
// getter
var active = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active" );

// setter
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
, your simply changing the boolean to true or false , that makes it active or not